# InstaLoader simplejson.errors.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python

I've been trying to fix this but couldn't find a fix anywhere, I'm using `InstaLoader 4.5.5`.

I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 145, in <module>
    attemptRoutine()
  File "main.py", line 136, in attemptRoutine
    routine()
  File "main.py", line 90, in routine
    scrapeVideos(username = IG_USERNAME,
  File "/media/ubuntu/EE81-0482/Python/auto_Yt/scrape_videos.py", line 18, in scrapeVideos
    L.login(username, password)  
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/instaloader/instaloader.py", line 483, in login
    self.context.login(user, passwd)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/instaloader/instaloadercontext.py", line 224, in login
    resp_json = login.json()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 897, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/__init__.py", line 518, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 370, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 400, in raw_decode
    return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end())
simplejson.errors.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I've been trying to scrape videos from meme pages for a youtube channel, Code taken from:
[automated_youtube_channel Github](https://github.com/nathan-149/automated_youtube_channel)

Comment: Error can means that it can't get JSON from server. Today was question about PyTube which has problem to connect with YouTube because YouTube changed some elements on server and now module need also changes. maybe you have the same problem. Maybe module need changes and you have to wait for newer version.

Comment: see [issues](https://github.com/nathan-149/automated_youtube_channel/issues) on page from your link. Other people has the same problem. It can be problem with server and you may need to wait for newer version. And you should rather ask for help on `issues`

Comment: @furas I was using the version supplied in the requirements.txt, I removed then reinstalled and works perfectly fine. Thanks for mentioning I may need a newer version